# trying to access in code behind to an ASP:Repeater ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

Environment is an oldish application written in ASP 2.0.

I have this code that displays a DB source into an ASP:repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server"    DataSourceID="DS" OnItemDataBound="On_Repeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("My_DB_Field") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It works fine.
However, I would like to change the code so that sometimes CB.Text = My_DB_Field (as now) and sometimes it equals an other DB field value.
So I will need to do that into code behind's On_Repeater_ItemDataBound method.

But how can I access the template item DB fields inside this method?

In other words, what is the equivalent of

```
Text='<%# Eval("My_DB_Field") %>'
```

in code behind?

I see that what I am looking for can be accessed via:
`((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row.ItemArray[12]`
However, Row.ItemArray is an object[]

So it looks extremely hazardous to hard-code the DB field ID (12).
I'd like to know if there is a dictionary like object so I can access it via the DB field name ("My_DB_Field")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataBinder.Eval`

```
string value = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "My_DB_Field").ToString();
```

or

```
DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
string value = row["My_DB_Field"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thx so much for your kind assistance :)